# Blackberry - how to Display Dynamic Table Layout view

Tags: blackberry

In Blackberry, How to Create Dynamic Layout View which data is parsed and loaded using XML or JSON Parser and Table Layout be like as below

```
----------------------- 
image| Text 
----------------------- 
image|Text | image|Text 
----------------------- 
image|Text | image|Text 
----------------------- 
----------------------- 
image| Text 
----------------------- 
image|Text | image|Text 
----------------------- 
image|Text | image|Text 
-----------------------
```

Please Provide Sample Code

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FlowFieldManager](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/FlowFieldManager.html), it should do what you want.