# How to use ListField Class to display rows of text?

Tags: blackberry

Plz help me in cited to above mentioned tropic
   The row should contain

```
  row1      text    text  img
            text    text

  row2      text    text img
            text    text
```

Every row should look like that. Actually it is going to display multiple extracted JSON data in rows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blackberry - how to Display Dynamic Table Layout view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873168/blackberry-how-to-display-dynamic-table-layout-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call `list.setRowHeight()` to give yourself enough room to display all of this, and then in your ListFieldCallback's `drawListRow()` method, paint each Field how you'd like. If you need further explanation post a comment and I can expand.

Edit for comments:
You can do something like this in drawListRow()

```
public void drawListRow(Graphics graphics, int index, int y, int width) {
    //get your strings from the vector, I'm calling them t1 and t2 and the image img

    //draw the top line of text
    graphics.drawText(t1, 0, y);
    //draw the second line of text
    graphics.drawText(t1, 0, y + getFont().getHeight()); //You can cache the font height for performance if you want

    //draw the bitmap
    graphics.drawText(width - img.getWidth(), y, img, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanx....Plz give the code. Actually this text are datas obtained by parsing JSON String. I have collected the JSON sttring in a vector and i don't know how to display this field in ListField.

Comment: yes the above code works but now there arise a problem. If i need to display three text vertically in a row , the third txt is not shown and now i need to increase the height of individual row . How can I override this ListField class? Plz give the whole code

Comment: You can't change the height of individual rows

Comment: But i have seen that the height of the row can be increased.   Plz help if anyone can...

Comment: You can set the height of all of the rows with `list.setRowHeight()` as said in my answer.